# C#. Writing settings to XML file

Tags: c#, xml

I have some names of files. I am creating a XML file to store them. When application runs second time it should recognize those file names. Here is my code:

```
XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("settings.xml");
writer.WriteStartElement("DialogCreater");
writer.WriteElementString("conditionsFile", conditionsFile);
writer.WriteEndElement();
writer.Close();
```

But when I use those file names like this:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(charactersFile);
```

It gives me an error.

> System.NotSupportedException

Here how I read them from XML file:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("settings.xml");
XmlNodeList node = doc.GetElementsByTagName("files");
foreach (XmlNode n in node[0].ChildNodes)
{
    if (n.Name == "conditionsFile") conditionsFile = n.InnerText;
}
```

Comment: Either the file name charactersFile is wrong or the program has the file opened and doesn't allow you to read the file.

Comment: doc.GetElementsByTagName("files"); ??? Above you have created only DialogCreater tag

Comment: add the containing of the result xml file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NotSupportedException
```

path is in an invalid format according to msdn documentation. you can fix it by checking path exist or not before reading from it[More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
string path = @"c:\temp\MyTest.txt";
// This text is added only once to the file.
if (!File.Exists(path))
{
    //file exist
}
```